# jenkins can't recognise known_hosts file

Tags: centos, jenkins

I am using Centos 7. I have Jenkins installed on it

I have copied `~/.ssh` directory to `/var/lib/jenkins/`

Contents of .ssh directory are

1. authorized_keys
2. id_rsa
3. id_rsa.pub
4. known_hosts

Now when I am trying to Launch slave it is still giving error .

```
[SSH] Opening SSH connection to :22.
/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts [SSH] No Known Hosts file was found at 
/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts. 
Please ensure one is created at this path and that Jenkins can read it.
```

This is how slave configuration looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `known_hosts` file needs to be readable by the Jenkins user and mode 600.

As the error message says (emphasis mine):

> Please ensure [the known hosts file] is created at this path **and that Jenkins can read it.**

Assuming your Jenkins user is `jenkins`, here is how to ensure the contents of Jenkins' SSH directory have the right permissions:

```
sudo chown -Rh jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/{authorized_keys,id_rsa,known_hosts}
```